# Confused as to when to use the root test for convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm reading my textbook and I see this:

[image]

and

> Only use the Root Test if you have exponential forms where the exponent is n . If some other component, like a polynomial in n, ln n , n! , n or 3 n is present, don’t use the Root Test.

What does `polynomial in n` mean? Does that mean just $n$ and not $n^n$?

and

[image]
[image]

The above fails I see because the n in the numerator causes problems when the root test is applied. So when is the best time to use the root test to test for convergence? Just look for the exponent `n` I guess?

Comment: "polynomial in $n$" means an expression which is a sum of terms of the form $an^k$, where $a$ is constant and $k$ is a positive integer.

Comment: If you have a series of the type $\sum a_n^{n}$ where $\lim a_n$ is easy to calculate then root test is obviously the most convenient. For  a series of the form $\sum a_n^{n+3\ln \, n-n^{4}}$ root test is difficulty to apply in general.

Comment: $\infty^0$ is gibberish. If $f(n)\to \infty$ and $g(n)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ then $f(n)^{g(n)}$ may fail to converge (in any possible way), or may converge to any non-negative number. We have $\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{1/n}=1$ because  $0=\lim_{n\to \infty} (\ln n)/n=\lim_{n\to \infty}\ln (n^{1/n})$ and because $ \ln$ is a continuous function. And there are other ways to prove it, without  using  logarithms.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{1/n}=1$ is a useful tool. It makes the root test more easily applicable to a broader class of series. Generally, try the ratio test first, because it's usually easier.

Comment: Another useful tool for the root test, when factorials are involved, is Stirling's Formula $\lim_{n\to \infty} G(n)=1/\sqrt {2\pi},$ where $G(n)=(n!)^{-1}(n/e)^n\sqrt n,$ which is deep. But for many applications it suffices to know that $G(n)$ converges to  a positive limit ( which can be proved by elementary methods). Because that implies that $(n!)^{-1/n}\cdot (n/e)$ converges to $1.$